# Laravel and package installation with Composer

Tags: php, laravel, installation, package, composer-php

I'm new using laravel (Laravel 5) and I try to install the [**Stylist**](https://github.com/floatingpointsoftware/stylist) package via **Composer** but not works. This is what I did:

- Get the package via composer ()
- Add `'FloatingPoint\Stylist\StylistServiceProvider',` to `config/app.php` file
- Use `php artisan vendor:publish` to get the Stylist's config file
- Make a `themes` dir (with subdirs and `theme.json` file to test) and configure into Stylist's config file

Now: I don't know where I need to add the `Stylist::registerPath('/absolute/path/to/theme', true);` line

Pd: sorry for my bad english :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would make a ThemeServiceProvider where you can register and activate your themes.